# How to run below the code in cpanel

Tags: php, html, css

I have used below the code for converting PPT to IMG

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
    $ppApp->Visible = True;
    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); 
    $FileName = "MyPP";
    $ppName = "MySlides.ppt";


    //*** Open Document ***//
    $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));

    //*** Save Document ***//
    $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17);  //'*** 18=PNG, 19=BMP **'
    //$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),17);

    $ppApp->Quit;
    $ppApp = null;
?>
PowerPoint Created to Folder <b><?php $FileName?></b>
</body>
</html>
```

its working only in http : //localhost but if I use this same code in my web-server(cpanel hosted location) location its showing following error.

**Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/domainname/public_html/index.php on line 9**

Comment: cpanel howted location

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is running Linux.

In order to install the PHP extension required to use the Component Object Model ([`php_com_dotnet`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.com.php) this gives access to the `COM` Class) you need to be running Windows Server and you'll also need to have Microsoft PowerPoint installed on that Windows Server in order to manipulate the PPT in the way that you are trying to.

Comment: how to install can you please let me know step by stemp procedure am new in webserver

Comment: @Puthuvannam - No I can't give you a step by step as you need an entirely different Operating System. There are web hosting companies that offer Windows Hosting you should google them to see if a product suits your needs