# How to Clear this Error

Tags: php, html, css

I have used below the code for converting PPT to IMG

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
    $ppApp->Visible = True;
    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); 
    $FileName = "MyPP";
    $ppName = "MySlides.ppt";


    //*** Open Document ***//
    $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));

    //*** Save Document ***//
    $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17);  //'*** 18=PNG, 19=BMP **'
    //$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),17);

    $ppApp->Quit;
    $ppApp = null;
?>
PowerPoint Created to Folder <b><?php $FileName?></b>
</body>
</html>
```

when run this code in my local system by using xamp, its working only in http : //localhost but if I use this same code in my web-server(cpanel hosted location) location its showing following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/domainname/public_html/index.php on line 9

Comment: which version of php you are using in the webserver ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run below the code in cpanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486207/how-to-run-below-the-code-in-cpanel)

Comment: hot to find the php version and and so many php.ini file in my cepanel so please let me know exact location

Comment: @Phil not possible duplicate it is the exact duplicate :P

Comment: @Sabari Couldn't be bothered correcting the default text.

Answer (score 2):

PHP Manual States ..

> As of PHP 5.3.15 / 5.4.5, this(COM) extension requires php_com_dotnet.dll
>   to be enabled inside of php.ini in order to use these functions.

[`Installation Doc from PHP Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php)

Comment: hot to find the php version and how to add that line can you guide me

Comment: You should ask the support team of your webhosting provider, tell them you need this component and they will enable it.

Comment: so many php.ini file in my cepanel so please let me know exact location

Comment: @Puthuvannam I don't know if you are trolling or asking a real question. Just tell your host to do it

Answer (score 1):

From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core.you have to add COM support in php.ini:

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

The extension is included with php 5.4.5 for Windows. So only you are not seeing it in your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for this extension in server.

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

in your php.ini